# Я, в предзнаменование/предзнаменовании Нового года, Арине-мисс супер-открытку-коверт приготовил-таки

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я, в предзнаменование/предзнаменовании Нового года, Арине-мисс супер-открытку-коверт приготовил-таки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я, **в предзнаменование** Нового года, Арине-мисс супер-открытку-коверт приготовил-таки.*

В предзнаменование (= в знак): направленный В.п, окончание ***Е***.

**ПРЕДЗНАМЕНОВАНИЕ**, -я; ср. **Признак**, предвещающий близость, **наступление** чего-л.; предвестие, примета. Счастливое, грозное п. Дурное, доброе п. П. великих потрясений.

**Пример:**

*На этом я проснулся да тут же и подумал, что этот сон наверно неспроста и **в предзнаменование** какого-нибудь важного, решительного **события** в моей жизни.* Ф. Ф. Тютчев. На скалах и долинах Дагестана (1903)

Comment: А если это обстоятельство времени, то через И. Или нет?

Comment: В этом значении  (П.п.) слово практически не используется, мне не удалось найти таких примеров в Нацкорпусе или в Карте слов.  В основном И.п. или Т.п., редко В.п. По определению это "знак, признак", и трудно представить слово в качестве наречия времени.  Возможно, это речевая ошибка.